# Add rounded corners to images

Tags: android, kotlin

How can I add rounded corners to images and a little drop shadow so it looks like the attached?

Here's what I have in my activity

```
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <!-- Content here -->

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="107dp"
            android:layout_height="166dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:translationZ="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60941554/imageview-rejecting-rounded-corners-and-borders-of-parent/60951786#60951786

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImageView rejecting rounded corners and borders of parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60941554/imageview-rejecting-rounded-corners-and-borders-of-parent)

Comment: use a `CardView` as root layout ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different options.

- You can use a `CardView` as root layout.
- You can apply rounded corners to your `LinearLayout` using a  `MaterialShapeDrawable` ([check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61144528/programatically-change-background-of-drawable-maintaining-the-corner-radius/61193380#61193380))
- starting with the version **`1.2.0-alpha03`** of the the [Material Components Library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) you can change the `ImageView` to the new **`ShapeableImageView`**.

Something like:

```
  <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
      ...
      app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/roundedImageView"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_custom_image" />
```

with:

```
  <style name="roundedImageView" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">8dp</item>
  </style>
```

Or programmatically:

```
float radius = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.corner_radius);
imageView.setShapeAppearanceModel(imageView.getShapeAppearanceModel()
    .toBuilder()
    .setAllCorners(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,radius)
    .build());
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use something ready such that https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

or make your custom background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <!-- View background color -->
    <solid
        android:color="@color/colorPrimary" >
    </solid>
    <!-- The radius makes the corners rounded -->
    <corners
        android:radius="8dp" >
    </corners>

</shape>
```

you can change the radius in corners tag
then mark it as background

```
 <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"/>
```